# EventBus - threadMode not regonized as @Subscribe annotation property :cannot resolve method threadMode

Tags: android, annotations, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I am using GreenRobot EventBus ,  I wanted to define some Threading properties, according to docs,

However, when I write:

```
 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onShowNotification(NotificationEvent event) {
        if(event == NotificationEvent.bannerEvent) {
            updateContents();
        }
    }
```

I get an error that threadMode is not recognized by compiler specifying method:  `cannot resolve method 'threadMode'`

i have on my `gradle` file:

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

Comment: Do you mind adding the exact error message to your question?

Comment: @fangzhzh, i added the error message; sorry I thought it was intuitive by saying that compiler didn't recognize it.

Comment: I suspect that your project uses another library which also has a @subscribe keyword. Can you try CMD+B when the cursor in the "@Subscriber" and go to the definition, does it go to org.greenrobot.eventbu.Subscribe?

Comment: @fangzhzh wow you are right, somehow it is using the com.google.common.eventbus instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your project uses another library which also has a `@Subscribe` keyword. Can you try CMD+B when the cursor in the `@Subscriber` and go to the definition, does it go to `org.greenrobot.eventbu.Subscribe`?

**The takeaway here**: when error `cannot resolve method` happens, you can always go to the definition to check what happens there :)